# How to calculate the weekend when counting a date range in Google Sheets?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, weekend

I have the below columns

```
StartDate   EndDate    CountDay
01 May 20   05 May 20     ?
```

As you see, 01 May is Friday, so from 01-05 May if we count all days including weekend it will be 4 days.

What I want is on column "CountDay" it only counts the Workdays, not the weekend.
SO the expected result would be 2.

Anyone know how to do it using a formula in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do you consider Fridays as part of the weekend?**

**If yes**, then you could also try the following formula:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A10, B10,"0000111")
```

[image: weekend including Fridays as weekend]

**If not**, please use this formula:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A10, B10)
```

#### How the formulas work.

By using the function `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` we can *"adjust"* the weekend (non-working weekdays) to our liking.
In this case we account Fridays as our non-working weekdays by using as the 3rd parameter `0000111` instead of the default `0000011` where every `0` represents a working weekday and every `1` a non-working weekday.

***(Very useful for people working part-time)***

Someone who has ***part-time work on only Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays*** and wants to calculate the working days `Friday, 1 May 2020 - Tuesday, 30 June 2020` could adjust the formula to:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A10, B10,"0101011")
```

[image: Calculating part-time workdays for only Mndays, Wednesdays, Fridays]

---

As explained on the [official Google help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3295902) for `NETWORKDAYS.INTL`

> weekend – [ OPTIONAL – 1 by default ] – A number or string representing which days of the week are considered weekends.
>
> - String method: Weekends can be specified using seven 0s and 1s, where the first number in the set represents Monday and the last number is for Sunday. A zero means that the day is a work day, a 1 means that the day is a weekend. For example, “0000011” would mean Saturday and Sunday are weekends.
> - Number method: Instead of using the string method above, a single number can be used. 1 = Saturday/Sunday are weekends, 2 = Sunday/Monday and this pattern repeats until 7 = Friday/Saturday. 11 = Sunday is the only weekend day, 12 = Monday is the only weekend day and this pattern repeats until 17 = Saturday is the only weekend day.

Answer (score 0):

I just found how to do it:

```
=if(weeknum(A10)<weeknum(B10),B10-A10-2*(weeknum(B10)-weeknum(A10)),B10-A10)
```

something like that